# Improve InnoDB count(*) performance

Tags: mysql, performance, count, innodb

I got a large table with million of records. I have to do a `count(*)` for a certain criteria and there is no way I can get rid of it.

`count()` with `InnoDB` is very expensive. I have been trying to figure out different configurations for MySQL but all in vain. Can't speed up the count. The application requires the result to be less than 1 second because there are other dependent queries to run.

Any indexes are not helping because of the way InnoDB counts.

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) FROM `callrequests` WHERE active_call = 1;
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type  | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | callrequests | index | NULL          | active_call | 6       | NULL | 5271135 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+

mysql> show index from callrequests;
+--------------+------------+------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name                     | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------------+------------+------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| callrequests |          0 | PRIMARY                      |            1 | id           | A         |     5271135 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| callrequests |          0 | PRIMARY                      |            2 | campaign_id  | A         |     5271135 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| callrequests |          0 | unique_contact               |            1 | campaign_id  | A         |        4849 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| callrequests |          0 | unique_contact               |            2 | contact_id   | A         |     5271135 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| callrequests |          0 | unique_contact               |            3 | contact      | A         |     5271135 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| callrequests |          1 | fk_callrequest_campaign1_idx |            1 | campaign_id  | A         |          10 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| callrequests |          1 | index4                       |            1 | campaign_id  | A         |        2506 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| callrequests |          1 | index4                       |            2 | contact      | A         |     5271135 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| callrequests |          1 | phonbook_id_index            |            1 | phonebook_id | A         |          10 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| callrequests |          1 | dnc_group_id_index           |            1 | dnc_group_id | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| callrequests |          1 | active_call                  |            1 | campaign_id  | A         |          12 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| callrequests |          1 | active_call                  |            2 | active_call  | A         |          16 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| callrequests |          1 | call_status                  |            1 | call_status  | A         |        2518 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| callrequests |          1 | call_status                  |            2 | processed    | A         |        2518 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| callrequests |          1 | call_status                  |            3 | active_call  | A         |        2518 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------------+------------+------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

The server is 
`Xeon machine with 12 CPU cores and 64 GB RAM dedicated 5.6.14-62.0 Percona Server`

My `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is `38 GB` and all of data sits in innodb buffer pool.

Comment: `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is 38 GB ?

Comment: Do you have index on active_call? As horribly formatted EXPLAIN suggests the index does exist, but MySQL prefers full index scan. Can you show show indexes from callrequests\G ?

Comment: @fancyPants : I Know that i was just confirming as in question GB is not mentioned.

Comment: Well, InnoDB prefers to use full index scan anyway. Not sure how can this be improved. @AbdulManaf Yes the buffer pool is 38 GB, it was a type now fixed.

Comment: True, the Index was not proper. New index on active_call is running very fast per NBhatti.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Difference between innodb and myisam concerning counting

Please notice that counting with `WHERE` is not slower with InnoDB than it would be with MyISAM. Only a very bare

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table
```

can be computed faster with MyISAM as this number is stored in MyISAMs table metadata.

If you have a query with `WHERE` constraint for example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE active_calls = 1
```

the query needs to access the table data in both storage engines and there should be no notable performance difference between MyISAM and InnoDB.

## Concerning your specific problem

Please see that your query does not use any proper index. This is not because InnoDB "prefers" a full table scan, but because there exists no proper index.

You have a combined index `(campaign_id, active_calls)`, but `active_calls` is the second part of the index. As long as the first part is not used in the query, MySQL has no easy access to the second part.

What you want for this simple count query is another index `(active_calls)` only on this one column. It should run fast then.

Comment: Also to add, MyISAM uses table lock and its possible to keep track of number of record. But in the case of innodb, as writes happens with row level lock, it is very hard to handle the count and innodb has to do a table scan for each count(*). There is an inherent difference in the purpose of both engines

Comment: @GhostGambler True, the Index was not proper. New index is running very fast.

Answer (score 6):

I found way to improve the performance of count(*):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id > 0;
```

Comment: I see the same. But why is that so?

Comment: what the sorcery is this?  its magically faster than only count(*) by 50x

Comment: Then magic happened.

Comment: Would need to look at EXPLAIN to be sure, but suspect it that is an index on `id` column that can be used (even the primary key index) - whereas without any where cluase it full table scan.

Comment: In my particular case it doubled the time taken to count

Comment: in our case it's actually worked and reduced the number of rows to scan by half. but can someone maybe elaborate more on how exactly does the rows count is halved when the innodb engine is using the PK?

Comment: you need to make sure you avoid memory cache, SQL_NO_CACHE

Answer (score 5):

COUNT(*) for Innodb Tables - Percona Database Performance Blog
https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/12/01/count-for-innodb-tables/

So if you have query like **SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER** It will be much `faster` for *MyISAM* (MEMORY and some others) tables because they would simply read number of rows in the table from stored value. *Innodb* will however need to perform `full table scan` or `full index scan` because it does not have such counter, it also can’t be solved by simple singe counter for Innodb tables as different transactions may see different number of rows in the table.

If you have query like **SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IMAGE WHERE USER_ID=5** this query will be executed same way both for MyISAM and Innodb tables by performing `index range scan`. This can be faster or slower both for MyISAM and Innodb depending on various conditions.

So remember Innodb is not slow for ALL COUNT(*) queries but only for very specific case of COUNT(*) query without WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

I found that COUNT(a secondary index) was fast as is, but I needed to play around in order to encourage mySQL to use the PRIMARY index.

I was able to use the PRIMARY index and get an significant speed increase without the condition of id>0  using:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM _test_offset WHERE id IS NOT NULL OR id IS NULL;
```

I also had to write the query in such a way that the column was only referred to once (for use in a mysql-rewriter plugin) prepared statement and found that this similar query works (cost was +10% time vs the above)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM _test_offset WHERE CASE WHEN id IS NOT NULL THEN TRUE ELSE TRUE END;
```

(In mySQL 5.7) it works for secondary indices, nullable/nonnullable indices and unique/non-unique indices.  In my simple test case it showed a 27x decrease in time required.

I would have put this as a comment under [Mark Khor's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4618188/mark-khor) answwer (since it's heavily derivative), but don't have sufficient rep.

Answer (score -5):

I had a similar issue. I also had a single int autoincrement primary key column. So I got around the problem by doing this:

```
select max(id) from table
```

Also the suggestion of @mark-khor (where id > 0) would have worked for me, but I don't understand why, so I went for the max(id)-value...

Comment: This is not accurate though.

Deleted records, or failed transactions can cause gaps in the counter. 

So it is possible to have 2 records, id 1 and 99. It's not correct to say you have 99 records.

Comment: Yes, this method only works in cases where data is only added and never deleted from a table. But if that is the kind of data you are working with, this is a nice super fast solution.

Comment: Even if you don't delete rows, max(id) is still not guaranteed to return the number of rows. Gaps in the id values can appear even if a transaction fails, or for other reasons.